# Will adding a robots meta tag stop Google Analytics from tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, meta

My question is pretty a simple one.

I want to stop my entire domain name from being indexed and showing up in search engine results.

However, I Also have Google Analytics on all pages and want to be able to look at stats.

My question is, by adding the robots meta tag to all pages:

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">`

Will this still allow Google Analytics to gather data, or will this be blocked?

How can I achieve this scenario?

For a bit of context: Yoast seem to explain how to restrict your pages from being indexed, but from what I can see they do not mention Google Analytics or any compromises in adding the robots meta tag:

https://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA doesn't crawl your website, hence neither robots.txt nor `<meta name="robots">` will have affect on it